# Laravel 5.2 subdomain route with slug url

Tags: laravel, routes

I have the dynamic urls, its looks like the following

```
domain.com/post/slug-url1
domain.com/imgs/slug-url1
```

i want url like this

```
post.domain.com/slug-url1
imgs.domain.com/slug-url1
```

any help

Comment: Sure you can! see https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing

Comment: Just make sure the correct dns records are set and add subdomain routing to your routes file.